# How could 'insightful' be translated into Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

How could you translate the meaning of 'insight' or 'insightful' into Spanish?

Note: 'Perspicaz' is not quite accurate..

Comment: How so?  What's wrong with *perspicaz*?  Also, could you give us two sample sentences, please, to show some context and how you want to use the words?  One for *insight* and one for *insightful*.  And is it okay if the translation ends up being more than one word?

Comment: For the translation to be accurate, some context is required.

Answer (score 3):

You could translate

> something ***insightful***

as

> algo ***esclarecedor***

[Esclarecer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GESJSuk) means the same that *to gain insight*, to acquire a clear comprehension about something

Here are examples to demonstrate uses, both as a noun (***esclarecimiento*** [ *insight* ]) or an adjective (***esclarecedor*** [*insightful*]):

> *El peritaje, llevado adelante por los especialístas informáticos, permitió el **esclarecimiento** del caso* [The technical inspection done by IT experts allowed gaining ***insight*** in the case]
>
> *La acción de los expertos informáticos fue **esclarecedora** en el caso* [Technical inspection carried on by IT experts was ***insightful*** in the case]

Alternatively, notice that the words ***revelación*** (noun) and ***revelador*** (adjective) will also work well with the two examples provided, since the meaning of **[revelar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WMv8YhT)** matches the sense of **esclarecer**)

***[Perspicaz](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SkJr6XL)*** in the other hand, —though close, as it refers to the power of something or someone capable to "gain insight"— works only as and adjective*, not a noun.

Comment: I've never seen a thing be insightful.  I've only seen that used to describe a person.

Comment: @aparente001: see this examples from a dictionary:  *"//a critical study featuring an insightful analysis of the novelist's recurring themes"*, or *"//The insightful dialogue often sounds like wishful thinking.*" (from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insightful#examples)

Comment: An ***analisis*** and ***dialogues*** are ***things*** (don't understand your downvote)

Comment: I agree with you. "insightful" can indeed refer to human activities which show how insightful the one doing them is.

Comment: @user2325442 - Thanks, you're right.  What an insightful answer!

Comment: insightful does describes ideas, etc. insightful ideas, contributions, etc. I agree with this answer but I don't much like all this English in the answers.

Comment: @lambie, when you say *"all this English in the answer*" you mean, to not like the translation  put between [square brackets]?  (I'm asking so to learn and  better my responses at this site)

Comment: When I discuss a term in a language, I use that term when the site/forum etc. is for that language. I would never, say, discuss translation into English from French, in French. Likewise, I don't like discussing translations into Spanish from English, in English. That is just my opinion. One should discuss these things in the target language, not the source language.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I see how it is a subjective issue. My take was to keep the conversation going  in the same language used by the person posting the question

Comment: @Lambie - From our [help pages](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):  *¿Debería escribir en español o en inglés?  Se prefiere el español, pero los dos idiomas son aceptados.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the key feature of insight in English is that it involves seeing into something deeply. If you have insight into a problem you have seen past the superficial surroundings and to the heart of the problem. So for me the [definition the DLE gives for *perspicaz*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SkJr6XL)

> 1. adj. Dicho de la vista, de la mirada, etc.: Muy agudas y que alcanzan mucho.
> 2. adj. Dicho del ingenio: Agudo y penetrativo.
> 3. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene ingenio perspicaz.

Is absolutely fine. The corresponding noun seems to be *perspicacia*

> 1. f. Agudeza y penetración de la vista.
> 2. f. Penetración de ingenio o entendimiento.

as *perspicacidad* is labeeled as being in disuse.

Comment: visión talvez, no vista

Comment: @Lambie - nota, DLE fue quien puso *vista*, no mdewey.  ¿Qué ganas con esta crítica?

Answer (score 0):

**sagaz**

This adjective is almost synonymous with  perspicaz, with a shade of difference.
Both capture something on the meaning of  'insightful'.  The corresponding noun is **sagacidad.**

Here's a [link](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=sagaz) to a dictionary translation into English,  and a few examples.

Comment: sagacity exists in English. insight is not sagacity.